# how to make this proper link list

Tags: c

```
// this is program designed to create Cd data base

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//=============================================
//LINKED LIST USED FOR CREATING THE DATABASE CD
//=============================================
struct CD_type_node
{
   int CDnum;
   char title[20];
   int CDcount;
   struct CD_type_node* next;
}

struct Artist_type_node // to create a linked list of CD's
{
   char Artist_name[20];
   struct CD_type_node* next;
}


int main()
{
   struct CD_type_node* mylist; // this points to the first node of the linked list
   mylist = (struct CD_type_node*)malloc(sizeof(struct CD_type_node));

   free(mylist);
   return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to create two linked lists. One is of CD database, other of artist. One of the restriction is this:

2) Create a `Artist_type_node` structure having the following fields:

- Artist’s name
- A pointer to a CD_type_node, to enable you to create a linked list for CDs.

it giving me errors is that the proper of making it?

it also ask me to create an array of 100 elements (in main) of type artist_type_node

Comment: You'll get better responses if you tell us what errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Your *immediate* problem is that you're missing semicolons from the end of the two structure statements. You should have:

```
struct CD_type_node
{
   int CDnum;
   char title[20];
   int CDcount;
   struct CD_type_node* next;
};

struct Artist_type_node // to create a linked list of CD's
{
   char Artist_name[20];
   struct CD_type_node* next;
};
```

To create an array of elements is no different to creating an array of integers with `int xyzzy[42];` (other than the type of course). Use something like:

```
struct Artist_type_node artist[100];
```